# QR Code Scanner with Lazarsoft. How to use the demo test.hml?

Tags: javascript, html, scanning

I'm working to create QR code scanner. I've been doing some research and I want to use https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode to decode QR code via web cam. The problem is I can't even run test.html file. I don't whether the codes needs addition in order to work, or I just don't know how to use it. I'm glad if someone can give me a step by step to make test.html working. At least, that's where I want to start cause I need to scan QR code through camera.

Comment: That's a question for developers. Isn't there any documentation? Also, chances are the webcam won't work from a `file:///` URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [this implementation](https://github.com/cirocosta/qcode-decoder). It's based on the LazarSoft library, but it actually contains, you know, examples of how to actually use the thing, not to mention that you just have to add one script to your page as opposed to 17 different ones that need to be added in a specific order. And not only do the examples work, but they're pretty easy to understand. You can find the demo page [here](http://cirocosta.github.io/qcode-decoder/).